# Auto case insensitive search a div with position reinitialised based on textbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/WBvTj/2/ to search a div based on input in textbox.

I want to make it auto-search enabled and should not depend upon "Submit" button. The search too must be case-insensitive.

Below is small code.

**X.html**

```
<input type="text" id="search-criteria"/>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search"/>
<div class="misc"> Manish
</div>
<div class="misc"> Ankur
</div>
<div class="misc"> Kumar
</div>
```

**X.js**

```
$('#search').click(function(){
    $('.misc').hide();
   var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
   $('.misc:contains("'+txt+'")').show();
});
```

------------**UPDATED SINCE MARKED DUPLICATE**-----------
 I tried with the code below,

```
$('#search-criteria').keyup(function(){
    $('.misc').hide();
    var regex = new RegExp($('#search-criteria').val(), 'i');
    $('.misc').filter(function() {
       return regex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
});
```

The problem is that the position of the div is not refreshed, it must be initialised to start of page. Since there are many div with class `misc`, after searching the expected div is visible as it is as the same position. I want it's position to be reinitialised.

Below is the supporting image,

**NO SEARCH**

[image]

**AFTER SEARCH**

[image]

Comment: Ahmad Alfy,  Zakaria Acharki.
no its not the same questions. he's asking a little different question. Please guys read the questions properly before responding or closing it.